# Converting hash to json format file [Perl]

Tags: perl

So I created a function that creates a hash `%data` which looks as follows:

```
{                                                                                                                                     
   '10517' => {                                                                                                                        
                'parent' => '10516', 
                'start' => 1545321095,
                'end' => 1545321098,
                'name' => 'A'                            
              },                                                                                                                       
   '10515' => {                                                                                                                        
                'parent' => '10513', 
                'start' => 1545321091,
                'end' => 1545321095,                    
                'name' => 'B'                           
              },                                                                                                                       
   '10514' => {                                                                                                                        
                'parent' => '10513',  
                'start' => 1545321091,
                'end' => 1545321095,                
                'name' => 'C'                      
              },                                                                                                                       
   '10516' => {                                                                                                                        
                'parent' => '10513',
                'start' => 1545321091,
                'end' => 1545321095,            
                'name' => 'D',                                                                                 
              },                                                                                                                       
   '10511' => {                                                                                                                        
                'parent' => '#####',
                'start' => 1545321090,
                'end' => 1545321099,            
                'name' => 'E'                                             
              },                                                                                                                       
   '10513' => {                                                                                                                        
                'parent' => '10511',
                'start' => 1545321091
                'end' => 1545321097             
                'name' => 'F'
              },                                                                                                                       
   '10518' => {                                                                                                                        
                'parent' => '10516',
                'start' => 1545321094,
                'end' => 1545321098,                    
                'name' => 'G',                                                                                               
              },                                                                                                                       
   '10519' => {                                                                                                                        
                'parent' => '10517',  
                'start' => 1545321096,
                'end' => 1545321097,            
                'name' => 'H',                                                          
              }                                                                                                                        
}
```

I would like to create a function which converts the data into the following output:

```
    {       
        'children' : [
            {
                'id' : 10511,
                'start' : 1545321090,
                'end' : 1545321099,         
                'name' : 'E'    
                'children' : [
                    {
                        'id' : 10513,
                        'start' : 1545321091,
                        'end' : 1545321097,             
                        'name' : 'F'    
                        'children' : [
                            {
                                'id' : 10516,
                                'start' : 1545321091,
                                'end' : 1545321095,         
                                'name' : 'D'            
                            },
                            {
                                'id' : 10514,
                                'start' : 1545321091,
                                'end' : 1545321095,
                                'name' : 'C'                                    
                            },
                            {
                                'id' : 10515,
                                'start' : 1545321091,
                                'end' : 1545321095,             
                                'name' : 'B'                                
                            },
                            {                                                                                                                        
                                'id' : '10517', 
                                'start' : 1545321095,
                                'end' : 1545321098,
                                'name' : 'A'                            
                             }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
```

It is not the fully expected data (meaning I was too lazy to add the other `ids` into the nested format).

I would like to convert the hash `%data` to be contain a tree-type format as was showen in the example. The final goal is to have a nested data so each parent hash an array of each children, and each one of those children has an array of their own children (if they have of course), and so on.

How should I approch this problem? I'm looking for the cleanest and most effiecnt way possible. Also If possible, without any additional modules.

Comment: *sigh* The most efficient way is to get over your reluctance to use additional modules. Then use the `JSON` module.

Comment: @mob Hey, thanks for the replay (hope I didn't ask something stupid). I will use the `JSON` module, I meant before converting into this format. Please check my edit.

Comment: So the question is how to convert your arrayref of structures into a tree structure. Please edit your question to reflect that, and leave out the irrelevant parts about JSON.

Comment: @Grinnz, thanks for the replay. hope that my edits succeed your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just push the child elements into a children array in the parent:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $data =
    {
     '10517' => {
                 'parent' => '10516',
                 'start' => 1545321095,
                 'end' => 1545321098,
                 'name' => 'A'
             },
     '10515' => {
                 'parent' => '10513',
                 'start' => 1545321091,
                 'end' => 1545321095,
                 'name' => 'B'
             },
     '10514' => {
                 'parent' => '10513',
                 'start' => 1545321091,
                 'end' => 1545321095,
                 'name' => 'C'
             },
     '10516' => {
                 'parent' => '10513',
                 'start' => 1545321091,
                 'end' => 1545321095,
                 'name' => 'D',
             },
     '10511' => {
                 'parent' => '#####',
                 'start' => 1545321090,
                 'end' => 1545321099,
                 'name' => 'E'
             },
     '10513' => {
                 'parent' => '10511',
                 'start' => 1545321091,
                 'end' => 1545321097,
                 'name' => 'F'
             },
     '10518' => {
                 'parent' => '10516',
                 'start' => 1545321094,
                 'end' => 1545321098,
                 'name' => 'G',
             },
     '10519' => {
                 'parent' => '10517',
                 'start' => 1545321096,
                 'end' => 1545321097,
                 'name' => 'H',
             }
 };
my $root = [];
for my $id (keys %$data) {
    my $entry = $data->{$id};
    $entry->{id} = $id;
    my $parent = $data->{$entry->{parent}};
    unless ($parent){
        push @$root, $entry
    }
    else{
        push @{$parent->{children}},$entry;
    }
}
print Dumper $root;
```

see

```
perldoc perldsc
```

for an introduction to nested data structures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to somehow not to change the data of` `%data`? I would use a deep copy of the `%data` hash but it is not so efficient. Any sophisticated way to change the algorithm (for example by using a new empty hash)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'efficient'?  There is nothing wrong with using `Storable` `dclone()` to (deep)copy `%data` before you build the tree. It will probably take less execution time than copying each key-value pair while iterating through the hash.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I thought of using another hash or array in order to insert the data into it, while iterating. The thing is I'll need to use the data of `%data` for other features so it will take time to deep copy the hash into another hash. I was wondering if its possible to use another hash (without deep copy) in order to do those iterations (maybe change the algorithm a bit).